# How can I pass StrictHostKeyChecking=no to svn+ssh?

Tags: linux, svn, ssh

I'm automating a process to checkout data from an SVN repository.  The issue happens when establishing a connection using svn+ssh it will prompt the end-user to accept the fingerprint from the host.

In a typical ssh connection I know I can just specify this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@ip
```

Is there any way to do something similar for an svn+ssh connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--non-interactive
```

(avoids prompts)

```
--trust-server-cert
```

(automatically trusts server cert)

[> more info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html)

...[and another possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257625/2325085)

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it deals with accepting unknown SSL certificates, but the question was about SSH host keys. I'm still looking for a solution to pass `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` into svn... So far the only thing I've found for svn+ssh is to add it into the ssh/config file as per [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/275788).