# "Error validating server certificate" on SVN checkout using SvnAnt

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant, svnant

I am new to Ant scripting. I am trying to checkout from an SVN repository using an Ant script. Here please find my Ant script below.

I am using Jenkins. Created a new project and set invoke ant build given the path of the ant file(ant target is dist).

I am able to checkout code by root user & able to do it in Jenkinstools (Source code management). But while executing from Jenkins -> Ant script build, it's showing the below error:

> Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

```
<project name="ProjectBuid" basedir=".">

<description>
    simple example build file
</description>
<property environment="env" />
<property name="svn.username" value="NANI" />
<property name="svn.password" value="Pandu" />
<property name="code.base.location" value="${env.WORKSPACE}" />
<property name="lib.home" value="..\lib" />
<property name="{svnPathParam}" value="https://Ip:port/Build/" />

<property name="jenkins-url" value="http://IP1" />
<property name="auth-username" value="root" />
<property name="auth-pwd" value="1231231231231" />
<property name="cli.prefix" value="AB_CLI_" />

<path id="mvn.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
</path>
<path id="svnant.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\svnant.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\svnClientAdapter.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\svnkit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\ganymed.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.home}\svnjavahl.jar" />
</path>

<tstamp>
    <format property="START_TIME" pattern="dd_MMM_yy_HH_mm_ss" />
</tstamp>
<property name="timestamp" value="${START_TIME}" />
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"
    classpath="${lib.home}\xmltask.jar" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${lib.home}\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml"
    classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
<svnSetting svnkit="false" javahl="false" id="svn.settings"
    username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}" />

<target name="dist" description="checkout code">
    <mkdir dir="${code.base.location}/${timestamp}" />
    <exec dir="${code.base.location}/${timestamp}" executable="svn">
        <arg value="co" />
        <arg value="${svnPathParam}" />
        <arg value="." />
    </exec>
    <!-- On executing above, error: Error validating server certificate for 
        'https://IP': [exec] - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. 
        Use the [exec] fingerprint to validate the certificate manually! [exec] - 
        The certificate hostname does not match. [exec] Certificate information: 
        [exec] - Hostname: IP [exec] - Valid: from XXXXXXX until yyyyyyyyyyyy [exec] 
        - Issuer: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [exec] - Fingerprint: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
        [exec] (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS 
        of 'https://Ip/build': Server certificate verification failed: certificate 
        issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted (https://IP) <!--Or 
        and also tried as below -->
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <checkout url="${svnPathParam}" destPath="${code.base.location}\${timestamp}" />
    </svn>
    <!-- On choosing above, error: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://Ip/build': Server 
        certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, 
        issuer is not trusted (https://IP) [svn] <Checkout> failed. -->
</target>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the https site through its IP instead of the host name? But.. couldn't you just run the `svn co` manually as the correct user and accept the certificate permanently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bypass ssl certificate validation in subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257323/bypass-ssl-certificate-validation-in-subversion)

Comment: If you're using Jenkins have you considered configuring the build job to do the checkout instead of running it from within ANT? If you want all the configuration local the new Jenkins pipeline feature allows you to keep build job config in a "Jenkinsfile". See: https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

The proper and valid solution is to use valid certificate that matches the FQDN or hostname you use to access the remote server. All other suggestions are just workarounds and they are kind of ugly. You should not bypass certificate validation because it is very bad from security point of view.