# svn checkout via cmd using java

Tags: java, svn, cmd

I am working on svn and trying to perform checkout operation via command prompt. Here is my command

```
svn co --username=username --password=password "the url from where I want to checkout" "Path where I want to checkout"
```

After running this command I am getting output like that

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://muurlname':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: PKI
 - Valid: from Jul 21 06:11:01 2015 GMT until Jul 21 06:41:01 2017 GMT
 - Issuer: PKI
 - Fingerprint: FD:9B:96:09:E9:A3:A8:A8:81:78:7E:71:28:FE:BB:93:BF:D0:15:C7
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

Now after pressing (t)emporarily or (p)ermanently my files are checkout.

```
Restored 'D:\Adapters Code SVN\SVN Adapter Test\testfile1.txt'
Restored 'D:\Adapters Code SVN\SVN Adapter Test\checkfile.txt'
Checked out revision 1465.
```

Now I am performing same via my java code and passing the command via processbuilder. But I am getting some SSL certificate verification error.

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://myurlname'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

Is there any command in svn where we can pass username and password and will not give any ssl certificate errrors?

Here is my java code to perform checkout operation

```
String url = "https://myWorkingUrl";
        String checkoutPath = "D:\\Adapters Code SVN\\SVN Adapter Test";
        String command = "svn checkout " + "--trust-server-cert --non-interactive "
                + "--username=hoh7kor --password=emmawatson " + "\"" + url + "\"" + " " + "\"" + checkoutPath + "\"";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        String line2;
        while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line2);
        }
```

Upon executing I am getting the errorstream output as

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://myUrl'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

Comment: Have you tried using a java lib, for example https://svnkit.com/ ?

The certificate issue will not be solved, but maybe you can tweak the client to suppress that warning.

Answer (score 0):

try the following options `svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive ...`

Caution:
be sure to really know what you do! for some reason this error is thrown (probably a wrong certificate, probably a self-signed certificate, probably a MITM!)

**UPDATE:** this options seems only to work for untrusted CAs (manpage: `accept SSL server certificates from unknown certificate authorities`)

but your certificate is invalid (instead of "just" not trusted).
see [bypass ssl certificate validation in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257323/bypass-ssl-certificate-validation-in-subversion) for further hints

Comment: Still getting the same error.
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

Comment: sorry, my bad.
the options seems only to work for untrusted CAs (manpage: `accept SSL server certificates from unknown certificate authorities`)